# How to plot multiple boxplots on same plot?

Tags: python, excel, matplotlib, boxplot

I would like to ask how I could make multiple boxplots appear on the same plot.

My code is as follows:

```
rolling = pd.read_excel ('rolling returns.xlsx')

eighteen = rolling['rolling eighteen']

nineteen = rolling['rolling nineteen']

plt.boxplot([eighteen, nineteen],
            labels = ['18 year returns', '19 year returns'], showfliers=True,showmeans=True
plt.show()
```

Unfortunately, only the following plot is created with one boxplot instead of two as desired:

Current plot:

[image]

If it is of any help, my Excel spreadsheet has two columns with data rows that differ in dimensions that I suspect could be the cause of the problems (Column 1 with 506 rows of numeric data and Column 2 with 253 rows of numeric data).

Any suggestions would be appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: Please post the contents of `'rolling returns.xlsx'`.

Comment: How does `rolling.describe()` look like?

Comment: @JohanC Hi, I am unsure of how to upload images via comments so please refer to the image in the following Google Drive: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1o7tQbDvR_K4mTirUBp4yItQvxATH_zRD?usp=sharing

Comment: @AnnZen, likewise, the Excel file is in the Google Drive

Comment: Well, you should [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70802436/edit) missing information to the post itself.  You shouldn't make images of text, but add the text itself to the post.  What seems to be happening is that pandas fills up the second column with NaNs to get to the same length for the whole dataframe.  And `plt.boxplot` doesn't show anything when it encounters a NaN.  If that is indeed the case, the solution would be to drop the NaNs in `nineteen`. (`nineteen = rolling['rolling nineteen'].dopna()` could work, or something similar)

Comment: A simple solution could be seaborn, which automatically ignores NaNs. `sns.boxplot(data=rolling)`.  https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html

Comment: @JohanC Thanks for the information, it really helped. Yeap, will take note of adding missing info to future posts as well. Thanks a bunch!